# GWT, how to fire event from widget or composite using EventBus from HandlerManager

Tags: events, gwt, event-handling, gwtp, gwt-platform

I have widget. I would like to fire an event as follow:

`fireEvent(new IndicatorStartEvent("Message"));`

But it dosn't work.

Normally I use Presenter for this (GWTP), but now I just would like to have regular widget:

```
public class FileUploadWidget extends Composite {
    MaterialFileUploader uploader = new MaterialFileUploader();

    @Inject
    public FileUploadWidget(String triggerId, EventBus eventBus) {
        super();
        initWidget(uploader);
        Window.alert("TEST Start");
        fireEvent(new IndicatorStartEvent("Message"));
    }
}
```

Here is event code:

```
public class IndicatorStartEvent extends GwtEvent<IndicatorStartEvent.IndicatorHandler> {
    public static Type<IndicatorHandler> TYPE = new Type<IndicatorHandler>();

    public interface IndicatorHandler extends EventHandler {
        void onIndicatorProgressStart(IndicatorStartEvent event);    
    }

    public interface IndicatorHandlers extends HasHandlers {
        HandlerRegistration addStartIndicatorHandler(IndicatorHandler handler);
    }


    private final String message;

    public IndicatorStartEvent(final String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public static Type<IndicatorHandler> getType() {
        return TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatch(final IndicatorHandler handler) {
        handler.onIndicatorProgressStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Type<IndicatorHandler> getAssociatedType() {
        return TYPE;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }    
}
```

This is my app presenter that handle the event:

```
public class AppPresenter extends TabContainerPresenter<AppPresenter.MyView, AppPresenter.MyProxy> implements AppUiHandlers
, IndicatorStartEvent.IndicatorHandler {
    @ProxyStandard
    public interface MyProxy extends Proxy<AppPresenter> {}
    public interface MyView extends TabView, HasUiHandlers<AppUiHandlers> {}
    @Override
    protected void onBind() {
        super.onBind();
        addRegisteredHandler(IndicatorStartEvent.getType(), this);
    }

    public void onAsyncCallFail(AsyncCallFailEvent event) {
    // fireEvent is executed from: com.gwtplatform.mvp.client;PresenterWidget
        fireEvent(new IndicatorStartEvent("Firing message"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onIndicatorProgressStart(IndicatorStartEvent event) {
        MaterialToast.fireToast("Indicator start: " + event.getMessage());
    }
}
```

If I fire this event from f.e.: `AppPresenter` (code above), or GwtRESTY filter/callback ass follow:

```
class ProgressIndicatorFilter implements DispatcherFilter {
    private AssistedInjectionFactory factory;
    private EventBus eventBus;

    @Inject
    public ProgressIndicatorFilter(AssistedInjectionFactory factory, EventBus eventBus) {
        this.factory = factory;
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean filter(Method method, RequestBuilder builder) {
        builder.setCallback(factory.createProgressIndicatorCallback(method));
        eventBus.fireEvent(new IndicatorStartEvent("Rest-Gwt Comunication started"));
        return true;
    }
}
```

It work as expected. But in those working examples it use `com.google.web.bindery.event.shared;EventBus`
The firing event doesnt work from widget, where is used:
`com.google.gwt.event.shared;HandlerManager;Bus` class. This class `Bus` extends `com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus` which extends the proper `EventBus` class from `com.google.web.bindery.event.shared;EventBus`.

So the widget's method fireEvent() use other `EventBus`.

Can anyone help me with this?

I've red official and this instruction:
http://blog.arcbees.com/2015/04/01/gwt-platform-event-best-practices-revisited/  but no luck so far. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because your `FileUploadWidget` uses it's own `EventBus` and not `GWTP` one that is also used in all of your `Presenters`.

There are two solutions:

1. Don't use `fireEvent(new IndicatorStartEvent("Message"))` but use `eventBus.fireEvent(new IndicatorStartEvent("Message"))` on the injected `EventBus` inside of your `Widget`.
2. Add the `IndicatorStartEvent` handler to your `FileUploadWidget` directly instead of using `addRegisteredHandler` on your `Presenter`.

I prefer solution 2:

```
public class FileUploadWidget extends Composite {
    MaterialFileUploader uploader = new MaterialFileUploader();

    @Inject
    public FileUploadWidget(String triggerId) {
        super();
        initWidget(uploader);
        Window.alert("TEST Start");
        fireEvent(new IndicatorStartEvent("Message"));
    }
}
```

In the `Presenter` or to be precise the `View` which uses your `FileUploadWidget`, you add a handler directly to the `FileUploadWidget`:

```
public class UploadView extends ViewWithUiHandlers<UploadUiHandlers> implements UploadPresenter.MyView,IndicatorStartEvent.IndicatorHandler {

    @UiField
    FileUploadWidget uploadWidget;

    @Inject
    public UploadView(final Binder binder) {
      widget = binder.createAndBindUi(this);    
      uploadWidget.addHandler(new IndicatorStartEvent.Handler(),this);
    }

    public void onIndicatorProgressStart(IndicatorStartEvent event) {
       MaterialToast.fireToast("Indicator start: " + event.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I've would like to stick with one IndicatorHandler Implementation, cause it is global action/event.

Comment: Then you need to use solution 1 and I would recommend to extend your `IndicatorStartEvent` from the generic `Event` instead of the `GwtEvent`. 

The reason why I prefer solution 2 is because it properly seperates concerns. I also have an `FileUploadWidget` and the widget fires `FileUploadStartEvent`, `FileUploadErrorEvent` and `FileUploadFinishedEvent`. My Presenter or View respectivaly that uses the `FileUploadWidget` handles those events and then fires for example a `NotificationEvent`. This way your `FileUploadWidget` is more generic and can be re-used more easily.